# React: How to setup function to use image from state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tensorflow2.0, filereader

I have an imageClassification function within my react component which gets the image to be classified from the img tag using document.getElementById `const img = document.getElementById('animal_image');`.

The image uploaded via file input updates the state which then gets passed to the the img tag
`<img id="animal_image" src={profileImg} alt="a test" />`

How can I update the code below so that the classifyImage function gets the image from when the image is upload via file input instead of getting from the img tag. i.e how can i access state within classifyImage function?

I looked at the filereader documentation but still could not figure out.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as automl from '@tensorflow/tfjs-automl';
import '@tensorflow/tfjs-backend-webgl';
import SampleDog from '../images/dogTest.jpg';
import './imageloader.css';

export class ImageLoader extends Component {

    state={
        profileImg: 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460_960_720.png'
      }

    fileSelectedHandle = (e) => {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = () =>{
         if(reader.readyState === 2){
            this.setState({profileImg: reader.result})
        }
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file)
    }


    classifyImage = async () => {
        const model = await automl.loadImageClassification('./image_classification_model_v1/model.json')

        const img = document.getElementById('animal_image');

        const predictions = await model.classify(img)

        console.log('predictions', predictions)
    }

    render() {

        const { profileImg } = this.state

        return (
            <div className="container">
               <div className="img-main">
                <h2>Image Classification Demo</h2>
                <p>Upload an image of a cat or dog to check the prediction score</p>
                <div >
                    <input 
                        type="file" 
                        accept="image/*"
                        name="image-upload"
                        id="input"
                        onChange={this.fileSelectedHandle} 
                    />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <img id="animal_image" src={profileImg} alt="a test" />
                </div>
                    
                <button 
                    className="img-loader-button"
                    onClick={() => this.classifyImage()}>Predict Score
                </button>
               </div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ImageLoader
```

[image]

Comment: But the current code works, doesn’t it? What’s your motivation to make the change?

Comment: Oh, do you mean you want to trigger `model.classify()` upon file upload, **without** the need to click the "Predict Score" button?

Comment: the code works but since I'm using react, i like to get the image to be processed from state which is getting update at file upload instead of using document.getElementBy

How can i achive something like this: const predictions = await model.classify(this.setState.profileImg)

Comment: i.e how can i access state within classifyImage function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the state you can just do `model.classify(this.state.profileImg)`. But that’s not gonna work directly cus tensorflow requires an image element or ImageData as input.

So I guess you’ll need to create an image element anyway.

```
fileSelectedHandle = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = () =>{
      if(reader.readyState === 2) {
        const img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = reader.result;
        this.setState({ profileImg: img });
      }
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file)
}
```

Comment: Ok that worked inside the imageclassify function but stop working in the img Tag

Comment: i got it working by adding two objects within state one for the imageclassify function and the other for the img tag ----  this.state = {
                currentImage: '',
                previewImage: 
}

Then within the fileSelectedHandle function assign the uploaded image to the currentImage and previewImage